# django forms non_field_errors customizing

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to have my own errors in django forms but I cant . as you can see I define my own error_messages but django is still using Its own errors.

app account / forms.py:

```
from django import forms


error_messages_email = {
    'required': 'please Fill-out this field',
    'invalid': 'invalid format for email',
    'max_length': 'max length is 40 chars',
}
error_messages = {
    'required': 'please Fill-out this field',
    'invalid': 'fields format is not valid',
    'max_length': 'max_length is 30 chars',
    'min_length': 'password should be at least 8 Chars',
}


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(error_messages=error_messages, max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                             'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(error_messages=error_messages, min_length=8, max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                                 'placeholder': 'Password'}))


class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(error_messages=error_messages, max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                             'placeholder': 'Username'}))

    email = forms.EmailField(error_messages=error_messages_email, max_length=40,
                             widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                            'placeholder': 'Email'}))

    password = forms.CharField(error_messages=error_messages, min_length=8, max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                                 'placeholder': 'Password'}))
```

and this is my apps template / signup.html:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block title %} Join {% endblock %}


{% block content %}

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}


            {{ form.username.errors }}
            <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}">Username:</label>
            {{ form.username }}<br>


            {{ form.email.errors }}
            <label for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">E-mail:</label>
            {{ form.email }}<br>


            {{ form.password.errors }}
            <label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}">Password:</label>
            {{ form.password }}<br>

        <input type="submit" value="signup" class="btn btn-primary" >

    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

the only problem is the errors other parts are working properly, in the browser I also change max_length to 50 and pass it a 50-char password and submit it and it works fine and shows my own error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about the answer , what I was doing wrong was that I didn't turn off templates validation so it wasn't using django validation error. simply where you defined your form template just do this:

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
```

put novalidate at the end of the form tag

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the `error_messages` keyword argument for a `Model` or a `ModelForm`.

As you're just using the standard `Form` this will not present the behaviour you're expecting.

You would need to change your `LoginForm` to inherit `ModelForm`. For example:

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(error_messages=error_messages, max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                             'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(error_messages=error_messages, min_length=8, max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                                 'placeholder': 'Password'}))

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields = ('username','password')
```